# Looking for a high temperature potentiometer

Tags: temperature, potentiometer

Does anyone know of any potentiometers that are rated up to 500 degrees F?

Comment: What's the point? You won't find any electronics to go with it that are rated to 500F.

Comment: @MattYoung - You can get wires that are rated WELL above 500F, and there's no reason the electronics have to be directly connected.

Comment: @MattYoung False, I found literally thousands of resistors rated to that temperature on Digi-Key.

Comment: @jakem That's cool and all, but silicon stops being a semiconductor long before 500F.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, the vitreous ceramic power type should be capable of 260°C, some are rated for it too.

[This one](http://www.vishay.com/docs/50026/rt25.pdf), for example, is rated for 320°C, which is more than 600°F.

[image]